# How Does Differential Scanning Calorimetry (DSC) Differentiate Between Exothermic and Endothermic Changes?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, polymers, differential-scanning-calorimetry

In DSC, heat flux difference between sample and reference is measured as function of temperature while temperature of sample and reference are maintained the same. DSC is often used for polymer analysis.

What I am not clear is how does DSC differentiate between exothermic and endothermic changes like for example crystalline and melting point of polymer since in both state changes temperature of sample remains the same? In both cases, to keep both sample and reference at the same temperature, heat flux for reference is going to decrease because if not temperature of reference would become bigger than of sample since we are giving latent heat to the sample.

Comment: The sign of peak (negative vs. positive) tell us endothermic or exothermic changes. Se his graph https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Example-of-DSC-thermogram-heat-flow-against-temperature-exothermic-peak-endothermic_fig6_264589742

Comment: In the case of melting, the reference temperature goes up and up but the sample temperature remains the same.

Comment: Yes, sign of peak tells us if transition is exothermic or endothermic. However, how can we determine if process is endo or exothermic if in the case of both, reference temperature goes up?

Comment: The substance used as reference must absolutely have no exothermic or endothermic transformation when heated

Comment: @Dario, It cannot be both exothermic and endothermic with positive or negative peak if the reference temperature is going up.

Comment: @DarioMirić, If you are still confused, think about a specific example.

Comment: @M.Farooq I am not saying that it can be both exothermic and endothermic. I am saying that in either way TEMPERATURE OF REFERENCE would go up if heat flux of reference is not reduced regardless of process being exothermic or endothermic because at transition temperature, temperature of sample is constant regardless of process being exothermic or endothermic.

Comment: @M.Farooq Example is given in main question. Crystalline and melting point, first being exothermic and other endothermic. When polymer sample is heated it goes first through crystalline point and than through melting point. In both cases heat flux given to reference needs to reduce in order to keep the same temperature of sample and reference since polymer has constant temperature at phase shift and so keeping heat flux of the reference the same would heat it up above temperature of the sample regardless if process is exo or endothermic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DSC, differential power (heat) is provided to keep the sample and the reference at the same temperature. The DSC plot has differential power on the y-axis and temperature on the x-axis. Also, as reference is chosen in such a way that it will not undergo any phase change or state change in the chosen temperature range. The instrumentation is not as simple as one might think. There are two separate heaters which can be *independently* controlled. I quote from O'Reilly's Instrumental Analysis book (slightly outdated but still a pretty good reference for concepts). It describes DSC nicely,

> There are two separate heating circuits, the average-heating
> controller and the differential heating circuit. In the
> average-temperature controller, the temperatures of the sample and
> reference are measured and averaged and the heat output of the average
> heater is automatically adjusted so that the average temperature of
> the sample and reference increases at a linear rate. The
> differential-temperature controller monitors the difference in
> temperature between the sample and reference and automatically adjusts
> the power to either the reference or sample chambers to keep the
> temperatures equal. The temperature of the sample is put on the x-axis
> (time) of a strip-chart (read "computer" today) recorder and the
> difference in power supplied to the two differential heaters is
> displayed on the y-axis. The power difference is calibrated in terms
> of calories per unit time.

Now imagine that you are heating the polymer and the reference, their temperature is increasing but their *difference* is zero. You have a flat baseline, as shown in the figure (Taken from Google Images). Let us continue heating both, *independently*, a temperature is reached when the polymer is melting. There is a phase change and the sample temperature is not changing anymore, but it needs heat to stay at that temperature. The reference, when brought to the melting point, does not need further heating, so its temperature is at the melting point of the sample. The sample is consuming power, but the reference is not. You get a negative peak in the DSC due to an endothermic process.

Apply the same idea to an exothermic process, such as crystallization. The temperature of the sample is becoming higher than the reference. The reference needs power to catch up to the temperature of the sample. The sample heater is not consuming power but the reference's heater is, in order to be at the same temperature. This time you get a positive (exothermic) peak.

[image: DSC]

Comment: Buttonwood, I think the OP wanted clarification about the principal/instrumentation due to a misconception that power is *continuously* being supplied to the reference.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I do agree with everything you said about melting. Reference is stopped heating while we need to heat the sample to keep the same temperature and to go through phase shift. I am not clear about crystallization since you've written that temperature of sample is increased during crystallization and that reference needs to catch up. However, what about latent heat of transition? Shouldn't temperature of the sample stay the same during phase change (crystallization) like in melting and any other phase change?

Comment: Since crystallization is exothermic we don't need to heat the sample until phase change happens, but if temperature stays the same during phase change we also don't need to and we shouldn't heat the reference to keep both at the same temperature.

Comment: Lets say, crystallization is exothermic at a temperature T. We need to heat the sample until it reaches the crystallization process. Now, the temperature of the sample cell is *spontaneously* increasing due to an exothermic process. It does *not* need heat at this moment from an external source. The reference cell must be heated now in order to bring the temperature at par with the sample.

Comment: As I said how can temperature of sample change during phase change which in this case is crystallization? When sample undergoes phase shift, its temperature stays the same until latent heat is provided. For example, When water is cooled, it turns to ice at 0°C. This phase change is also exothermic, but that doesn't mean that temperature increased. It is still 0°C until all water in the system is turned into ice (latent heat).  After that temperature can drop further.

Comment: Don't bring cooling at this moment. Let us stick to an exothermic process. The temperature must change due to an exothermic process. Don't you think so?

Comment: Well, actually I think you are correct. What confuses me is that usually in phase change, temperature is constant while in crystallization of polymers it is not as we discussed. What makes this exothermic phase change different from for example condensation which is also exothermic and in which temperature remains constant at phase change?

Comment: Temperature remains constant only for boiling and melting. Crystallization is a phase change and it is exothermic, leading to a temperature rise!

Comment: Okay, than everything has sense what you said. Thanks for clarification.